# Exception when calling DLL in delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll, error-handling

I have a procedure to call a function named [main()] from a DLL , this is the Caller procedure :

```
procedure call_dll(path:string);
var
  lib: HMODULE;
  mainfn: procedure(); stdcall;
begin
if FileExists(path) then
 begin
   try
     lib := LoadLibrary(PAnsiChar(path));
     Win32Check(lib <> 0);
     try
       @mainfn := GetProcAddress(lib, 'main');
       Win32Check(Assigned(mainfn));
       mainfn();
     finally
       FreeLibrary(lib);
     end;
   except
   end;
 end;
end;
```

Until yet every thing is working fine , I mean after writing the correct path of the DLL everything work without a problem but if I write a wrong path (other file path) in the path parameter it show me  a popup error that this is is not a Win32 DLL but I don't want to bother the user with this type of errors , so I need a function to check the DLL and if it's not then it will automatically ask for another file again without showing the popup error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your code that is raising the exception. Your code makes an explicit choice to handle errors by raising exceptions. The exception is raised by your code here:

```
Win32Check(lib <> 0);
```

If you don't want to raise an exception, don't use `Win32Check`. Instead check the value of `lib` and handle any errors by whatever means you see fit.

The same issue is present for your other use of `Win32Check`.

Of course you are swallowing all exceptions with your catch all exception handler. A catch all exception handler is usually a bad idea. I don't understand why you have included that. I think you should remove it.

So if you are seeing dialogs when running outside the debugger it follows that the system is producing the dialogs. You should be disabling the system's error message dialogs by calling [`SetErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621.aspx) on startup passing `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS`.

```
var
  Mode: DWORD;
....
Mode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
SetErrorMode(Mode or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
```

The somewhat clunky double call is explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx

Comment: Sorry sir but I'v made a `showmessage();` after every line and the error is caused by `lib := LoadLibrary(PAnsiChar(path));` not by `Win32Check` so what to do ?

Comment: Do what my final paragraph says. Call SetErrorMode to disable these dialogs. Your code is something of a mess in the way it handles errors. I think you've copied code from somewhere without understanding it.

Comment: hhhhhhhh That's true I'm a beginner but one day I will be able to write my own functions ;) , anyway I will try what you've said :) just a second

Comment: I just used the line `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);` and it works fine thaaaaaaaaank yoooooooooooou Sir

Comment: I can't give you a like but the day I will be able I will do :) :) :)

Comment: You should use the code as per my answer, at startup, otherwise you'll clear other error mode flags

Comment: Thank you so much , For sure I will do